# IOS: install .ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, adhoc, ipa

I created an adhoc version of my app (.ipa) and I sent it to a my friend; now he hasn't his mac, can he install .ipa without macbook (with iTunes) on his iPad? or .ipa is possible to install only through iTunes with a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in OTA installs, I would check out [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com), they are free and honestly fantastic.

Your friend can install the app using iTunes on Windows, but you will still need to make sure his UDID is added to the provisioning profile you built the app under. Otherwise it will fail on his end for code signing issues. TestFlight is good for making sure these are resolved before publishing. Otherwise you can put the .ipa file on dropbox for your friend to download.

Answer (score 2):

You can install with the itunes for Windows. 
If not use the "over the air" distribution. You'll provide an online link and he will install it directly in his phone. Search the web, there are many tutorials.

Comment: can you write me a link with a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

An Easiest Way to Install **.ipa** file to **iDevice** listed below.

1. Make sure your device **UDID** is registered in Developer account.
2. Select **Generic Device** as Target and go for **Archive** to Generate **.ipa** file. *(Hope you know the process of generating **.ipa** file for development)*
3. Once your **.ipa** file is ready then connect your iPhone or iPad to MacBook and select **Device and Simulator** in *X-Code* **Window** option.
4. Enable "**Connect Via Network**" Option in the Popped Up Window.
5. Click on to the + Symbol button which is located at below **Installed Application List** Section.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiZXd.png)
6. Select **.ipa** file which was earlier generated and saved at some location of your MacBook.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoVQA.png)
7. It will take few seconds to get your application installed on your device and will also appear in "**Installed Application List**" with build number.

INFO: you can do this with connecting the iDevice to your system or if your iDevice in same Network *(only if, you have enabled **Connect Via Network** to the device)*.